# Error when passing JSON string to MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

It's verys simple situation in fact, but I can't find solution: I need pass JSON string to my MVC Controller via jQuery ajax but Controller always receive null.
Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#makebooking").click(function (e) {
            var json;
            if ($("form").valid()) {
                var arr = $("form").serializeArray();
                json = JSON.stringify({ 'command': arr });
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Content("~/Booking/CreateBooking")",
                data: json,
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result != null) {
                        window.location = result;
                    } else {
                        $("#modalerror").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
                            var modal = $(this);
                            modal.find("#errormsg").text(result.Error);
                        });
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                }
            });
```

And Controller code is here:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateBooking(string command)
        {           
            byte[] stream = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(Request.Cookies["psw"].Value);
            byte[] decodedValue = MachineKey.Unprotect(stream, "all");
            var psw = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedValue);
            var a = _br.CreateBooking(User.Identity.Name, psw, command);
            return Json(a);
        }
```

I hope someone can have fresh look at this code and advise solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you posting a string (as opposed to posting your model)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain please?

Comment: The parameter in you method is `string command`? You have a form which I assume is based on a model, in which case you should post back you model using `data: $('form').serialize(),` and the method should be` public JsonResult CreateBooking(YourModel model)`

Comment: Yes, form based on ViewModel. Just now I tired to use model as parameter but without success - all data are null.

Comment: One more reason why I'm using string - I need process this data in order to re-create its as urlencoded string for calling external web service.

Comment: Did you also use `data: $('form').serialize(),` as well?

Comment: Seemed that's what I need. Please add this as answer -  data: $('form').serialize(),

Comment: @andrey.shedko you can not directly assign  or used command , first you need to  **deserialized**   it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of you POST method is `string` but you posting back `json`.

Change the method to

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateBooking(YourModel model)
```

and the script to

```
if ($("form").valid()) {
  var json = $('form').serialize(); // serialize the form values to json
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("CreateBooking", "CreateBooking")', // recommended
    data: json,
    ....
```

You model will be correctly bound in the POST method

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the entirety of your problem, but it looks like the url in your ajax call has a problem with the quotes. Try mixing single quotes with double quotes such as

```
url: "@Url.Content('~/Booking/CreateBooking')"
```

Comment: Definitely it's not the source of this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the inspector in chrome or firefox to check the call being made to the server?

Comment: Yes. I see that json data passed to ajax call, but missed somewhere between jQuery and Controller.

Comment: @hobenkr, This makes no difference (although its normal to use `url: '@Url.Action("CreateBooking", "Booking")',`

Comment: @stephenmuecke, you're right. Thanks for the correction. Andrey, I'm not familiar with asp, but do you get a response from the server in inspector? Maybe an error message or something?

Comment: @hobenkr, there only error concerned to null parameter, nothing else.